# grails spring-security plugin secures all controllers instead of just ones with @Secured annotation

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm following the [tutorials](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/tutorials.html) to use springsecurity authentication plugin.  I am using grails version 2.3.8 and spring-security-core:2.0-RC2.  It worked as expected to create the HelloWorld controller with the Secured annotation:

```
package basicauthdemo
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class HelloController {
    @Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
    def index() {
    render "Hello World"
    }
}
```

and then be presented with a login screen.

My question is that when I created another controller without the @Secured annotation.  I still get the login screen when navigating to that controller.  Spring security is now in charge of all access to my controllers as I can see from the filter-mapping in the generated web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

How to tell the plugin to allow open access to some controllers and not others?  I thought that this would be determined by presence of @Secured annotation but that only defines the role with permissions for the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html) for Spring Security Core plugin the default behavior is `pessimistic lockdown`

> ...  then any URL that has no request mappings (an annotation, entry
>   in controllerAnnotations.staticRules or interceptUrlMap, or a
>   Requestmap instance) will be denied to all users.

I highly recommend reading that particular section of the documentation to see how to configure the plugin for your use. Typically this will be modifying the default value of `rejectIfNoRule` and configuring the appropriate `staticRules`.